# ScrollMagic: make content hide the pinned area

Tags: javascript, css, scrollmagic

I am using ScrollMagic on my page. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="before-trigger">  
  </div>

  <div class="trigger" id="trigger">
  </div>

  <div class="pin-area" id="pin-area">
    This is a pinned area.
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum ...
  </div>

  <div class="content long">
    Lorem ipsum ...
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
var scene1 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger", triggerHook: 'onLeave'})
            .setPin("#pin-area")
            .addTo(controller);
```

Here is the jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5c3naLLg/17/

When scrolling down the page, I need to keep the pinned area, but only make invisible its overlap with `div.content` and the margin between two `div.content` sections. In another word, `div.content` and the margin between them need hide the pinned are when they overlap.

Answer (score 0):

With this library it is not possible not possible to achieve such result without "hooks".

**why:**

1. if you dont have "duration" in scene you will not unpin block.
2. if you will have "duration" the pined block will have greater height.
3. you cant use offset because you dont know content height and probably pinned block height.

**what you can try**

1. add custom listener and change pinned block class to have "fixed" position

**But it will not work as you want.**

**Better approach is to use bootstrap "scrollspy" combined with positioning css options also by bootstrap.**